# Take HTML area map and convert to d

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an area map using rect coordinates to highlight tables of a floor plan that are occupied.  Occupied tables will, when you hover over them, display the name of the company.  Easy enough.

What I want to do is take those coordinates and, using a div class for each table's coordinate, have a darker opacity over it for visual reference.  It's easy enough to calculate the top/left value for each table as well as calculating the width and height.  I just don't know how to take those values in jQuery to add this feature.  Here's a code snippet.

```
<img src="images/floor_plan_2011_small.png" alt="" usemap="#fp" />
<map name="fp" id="fp">
    <area shape="rect" coords="419,264,439,285" href="javascript://" title="Booth 73" alt="Booth 73" />
    <area shape="rect" coords="141,366,164,385" href="javascript://" title="Booth 62" alt="Booth 62" />
    <area shape="rect" coords="119,385,142,402" href="javascript://" title="Booth 64" alt="Booth 64" />
</map>
```

Comment: What is a "d"? Does your question title need amending?

Comment: If you're going to superimpose divs, why bother with an image map?

Comment: The image map was mostly due to legacy.  And Greg B, I forgot to finish the title before posting since the code examples were more important.  Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't bother with an image map. There's no point:

```
<div class="map">
    <img src="images/floor_plan_2011_small.png" />
    <a style="top:419px; right:264px; height:20px; width:21px" href="javascript://" title="Booth 73" />
    <a style="top:141px; right:366px; height:23px; width:19px" href="javascript://" title="Booth 62" />
    <a style="top:119px; right:385px; height:23px; width:27px" href="javascript://" title="Booth 64" />
</div>
```

Add this to your stylesheet, and you're done:

```
.map {
    position: relative;
}
.map a{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    background: black;
    opacity: 0.1;
}
.map a:hover{
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Comment: Worked well.  Simple and clean.

Answer (score 2):

If you add a container to the image, you can append an overlay to the image via JavaScript (or CSS):

```
<span id="img-span"><img src="images/floor_plan_2011_small.png" alt="" usemap="#fp" /></span>
<map name="fp" id="fp">
    <area shape="rect" coords="419,264,439,285" href="#" title="Booth 73" alt="Booth 73" />
    <area shape="rect" coords="141,366,164,385" href="#" title="Booth 62" alt="Booth 62" />
    <area shape="rect" coords="119,385,142,402" href="#" title="Booth 64" alt="Booth 64" />
</map>
```

JS--

```
//cache the span wrapper so it only has to be selected once
var $imgSpan = $('#img-span');

//bind a mouseleave event handler to the image map so when the user moves the cursor away from the image map the overlays will be removed
$('#fp').on('mouseleave', function () {
    $imgSpan.children('.overlay').remove();

//bind a mouseenter event handler to the image map area tags to create an overlay
}).children('area').on('mouseenter', function () {
    var $this  = $(this);
    $imgSpan.children('.overlay').remove()
            .prepend('<div class="overlay" style="top: ' + $this.css('top') + '; left: ' + $this.css('left') + '; width: ' + $this.css('width') + '; height: ' + $this.css('height') + ';"></div>');
});
```

CSS--

```
#img-span .overlay {
    position : absolute;
    opacity  : 0.6;
    filter   : alpha(opacity=60);
    z-index  : 1000;
}
```

Note: `.on()` is new in jQuery 1.7 and in this case is the same as `.bind()`.

Also-Note: I don't ever use image maps so I'm not sure that getting their `top`/`left`/`width`/`height` style properties is possible, if not then you can just get the `coords` attribute (`$(this).attr('coords')`) and parse it into the proper information.