# Graphical Map using CSS to drill down data

Tags: html, css, mapping

We have a new project where the client is a large housing complex. There are 10 areas/ district (district 1, district 2, etc .. ) and the client has provided a map.

Each district has 3-4 housing buildings, and each building has apartment buildings in them.
In each apartment building, are rooms for rent.

The client wants a Graphical Map for each level (Entire Area, Each District, Each Building, Each Apartment, Each Room).

The maps do not have perfect shapes.
[image]
We have the database completed, and we have drill down tabular data working.
We are looking to have a PNG of each levels map, and have some sort of overlaying DIV on specific regions of the map showing GREEN (available room) , RED (occupied) ,etc … OR a counter like 150 – available , 235- available.

The user can click on each map region and get more details by drilling down into other MAPS.
We have looked at creating a table with fields to generate html dynamically:

```
<map name="mapDistrict"> <area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" href=" Building/1" alt=" Building 1"> <area shape=" poly" coords="124,58,8" href=" Building/2" alt=" Building 2"> </map>
```

Is there a better solution ? We want to use CSS, Javascript (JQUERY) .. No FLASH!

Comment: Is it possible to export the map as an SVG, you could then use this: http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/data-visualisation/mouseover-effects-svgs

Answer (score 0):

I've done this type of real-estate map a number of times. What you're doing is pretty effective. You probably want to make a mapping of units to coordinates and a status for each using a JS array or JSON.

For entire buildings, you may want to look at this: http://www.netzgesta.de/mapper/, which converts map areas to coloured overlays.

There are some [other approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8857818/take-html-area-map-and-convert-to-d) you may want to consider that simple use square positioned links.

You can also hook up events to your area map to show overlays:

```
<area COORDS="80,88,120,125" HREF="#" onMouseOver="showUnit('a')">
```